# Cannot get the page fragment using jQuery load method

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's `load()` method to load a static page and extract a div from it. In my `index.html` page I have the following `div` which should be populated with this page fragment from test.html, as below:

```
<div id="attach" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: red;"></div>
```

The page fragment in test.html:

```
<div id="test">
    <h3>this is a page fragment</h3>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery as below:

```
$('#attach').load("/test.html #test");
```

Based on jQuery documentation this should work, however I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Q[a].exec is not a function

My version of jQuery is 1.10.2. I see that the page is loaded from the server but the page fragment is not extracted. Any thoughts as to why? Thanks.

Comment: If you check the request in the console, is the responseText the HTML in the format that you expect it to be?

Comment: Checking the XHR response, I get the full page (test.html) being returned. What other format should I expect it to be?

Comment: That should be fine then. Does an element with the `id` of `test` exist in the response, and is there only one of them?

Comment: Yes, to both questions. I have checked that.

Comment: I am at a loss to explain this then I'm afraid. Could you provide a link to a working example of the problem?

Comment: Nonetheless, thanks for your response. I am puzzled with it too as this should be an easy thing to do. Are you familiar with that particular jQuery error? any thoughts as what could cause this error?

Comment: No, I've not seen that error, although my assumption would be that it is caused by the HTML parser.

Comment: What is interesting is that if I remove the space between the page url and the id of the source page fragment (which is not the correct syntax), like so: `$('#attach').load("/test.html#test") `, then the full page does get inserted into the target div. Of course, I only want a fragment of the source page to be inserted instead.

Comment: In that case the request is working correctly and the problem is 100% on the HTML parser. Try running your HTML through a DOM checker tool to ensure that it's valid.

Comment: The page (test.html) is generated by a page generating extension, I have just added the source div to it. My IDE (Brackets) is validating the page as being correct. I can also use `$('#test')` after the source page is loaded to find the source div on the page.